# How to match values between Table 1 and Table 2, grab a corresponding value in Table 2, and then use it in an expression in Table 1

Tags: ms-access

I'm a bit of a novice/newbie in programming so forgive my naivety.  In MS Access 2013 I have two tables: Table 1 and Table 2.  I need a way to compare an entered value in [Table 1].[Field 6] to the values in [Table 2].[Field 2], and then when it finds the match take the corresponding row value in [Table 2].[Field 3] and use it in an expression in [Table 1].[Field 13].

I thought of using an "If" statement, but there are 10 potential values in the two tables that are being compared, thus the expression would get large and take forever to calculate.  Especially once Table 1 starts getting hundreds/thousands of records.

Can somebody show me the easiest/cleanest way to do this?

EDIT - adding more detail per request.

We sell truckloads, railcars, totes, etc. of commodities.  So when we enter in a contract, we would enter in 2 trucks, 3 railcars, 10 containers, etc. Each of these methods of transportation have different weights and are priced/sold differently ($/lb., $/metric ton, etc.) depending on the mode of transpot.  The idea was when a contract is entered, it would look at the mode of transport that was entered in [table 1].[field 6] , compare it to a master weight table (which was table 2), to get the number of pounds, tons, etc. that mode of transport was (lets call this variable 'x'), so i could use that number (along with volume and price in other fields in Table 1) to generate a Total revenue number in a new field in table 1.  = "x" *[volume]*[price].

As an example, say we sold 3 trucks.  When trucks was entered as the mode of transport, it would go lookup how much volume a truck is (which is 46,000 lbs) and then use that number in an expression. 46,000 x 3 trucks x $0.39/lb = $53,820.

I can create the shell, and can create the expression in the Revenue field.  I just can't figure out how to get variable "x" (the weight based on the compared tables) to put into the equation ="x" *[volume]*[price] without simply doing an "If" statement and including all 10 methods of transportation in the expression.  I would think there is a way to use a table or query to bring back "x" instead of a 10 different logical tests in an expression.

Comment: Adding some sample data and expected outputs might help; I'm having a difficult time parsing this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this SQL Statement:

`UPDATE [Table 1] INNER JOIN [Table 2] ON [Table 1].[Field 6]=[Table 2].[Field 2]
SET [Table 1].[Field 13] = [Table 2].[Field 3];`

You can add to `[Table 2].[Field 3]` `* [Table 1].[Other field]` or any number of fields, if you wish to multiply by volume and price.

You can also add `WHERE [Table 1].[Field key] = "current_record_key"` to make sure you only update the current entry. If you don't, it will update the entire Table 1 which can be a problem if weights change over time. Another choice if `WHERE [Table 1].[Field 13] IS NULL`, that way it will only update fields where Total revenue is empty.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This worked perfectly.  Pointing out the WHERE command was very helpful as well because it allowed me to add a seperate constraint.